# Модификация иконки FontAwesome

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: картинка]

Делаю сайт на Bootstrap и вот нужно используя FontAwesome вставить иконки.
Всё без проблем, да мне нужно немного отредактировать их, у меня конечно есть идея как их сделать через `before` и `after`, но это кажется извращения уже?
Должен ж быть способ править их. У меня сейчас как на на картинке 1, а надо как на картинке 2, правки не большие по сути.
Хотелось бы узнать какими можно средставами отредактировать стандартные иконки FontAwesome или это невозможно?

Comment: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/ Ищите пример `Stacked Icons`. Похоже не то, что Вы хотите

Comment: Доделывайте через css.

Comment: Можете создать картинку. и на этом сайте конвертировать в фонт https://icomoon.io/.

Answer (score 1):

Редактором шрифтов, как вариант.

Comment: А потом кто-нибудь, забыв про правки, обновит FontAwesome, и всё слетит к чертям. И, может, даже не заметят, что слетело. Лучше не надо так